# 'while' loops for sum of n numbers

Tags: c, while-loop

Im trying to find the sum of `n` numbers using a `while` loop so that it runs like so:

```
How many numbers: 3

-3,
4,
13,
The sum is: 14
```

However what I am getting is this:

```
How many numbers: 3

2,
1,
The sum is: 3
```

I dont understand it, because i set `i = 0`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)  {

    int numbers; 
    printf("How many numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &numbers);
    
    int sum = 0; 
    int i = 0; 
    while (i < numbers) {
        scanf("%d", &numbers);
        sum = sum + numbers; 
        i++; 
    }
    
    printf("The sum is: %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `numbers` changes since you're using it inside the loop to scan values. Use a diferent variable.

Comment: You are using `numbers` for two different tasks.  You need one variable for how many numbers to enter and another for each value you enter.

Comment: @PaulHankin — that isn't the problem here.  You are correct that the return value from `scanf()` should be checked, but the problem is caused by trying to store two different values in a single variable at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

A correct solution would be:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(void)  {
    
        int numbers; 
        printf("How many numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", &numbers);
        
        int sum = 0; 
        int i = 0; 
        int number; // use different variable for the input numbers
        while (i < numbers) {
            scanf("%d", &number);
            sum = sum + number; 
            i++; 
        }
        
        printf("The sum is: %d", sum);
        return 0;
   }
```

The problem was that you were using one variable for two different things.